# Invalid syntax in lapack testing file

Tags: python, mingw, lapack

When i compiled the LAPACK-3.4.2 with MinGW,i got a error like this:

```
File "./lapack_testing.py",line 17
         **except getopt.error, msg:
                            ^**
syntaxError:invalid syntax
Make:***[lapack_testing] Error 1
```

But i checked the lapack_testing.py,and there was no problem with the syntax.

Any idea?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception handling syntax is valid in Python 2. Starting with Python 3 that syntax is no longer valid. Seep [PEP 3110](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/).

So it looks like the code you are running is designed for Python 2 but you are trying to execute it on Python 3. The expedient solution is going to be to run the code under Python 2, as it is intended to run.